# $m(X) < \infty \implies m(B) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $(X, m)$ be a probability space and $T$ be a measure-preserving transformation on $X$. Let $A$ be a measurable set.

> Let $B = \{ x \in A : \forall k \in \Bbb N, T^k(x) \notin A\}$.

> Then $m(B) =0$.

I'm not sure why this claim is true.

This claim is part of a proof I'm reading of the Poincaré Recurrence Theorem.

I'm not sure if it helps, but here's the part of the proof before the claim $m(B) =0$ is made:

> $B$ is measurable, all the preimages $T^{-k} (B) $ are disjoint, and they have the same measure as $B$.

Comment: Please refrain from posting questions with titles consisting only of mathematical expressions/equations. These are discouraged due to technical reasons - see the second item of [Guidelines for good use of $\rm\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sum_k m(T^{-k}(B))=m(\bigcup_kT^{-k}(B))\leq m(X) <\infty$. If a series of real numbers is convergent then  the general term tends to $0$. So $m(T^{-k}(B))\to 0$ as $k \to \infty$. But $T$ is measure preserving so $m(T^{-k}(B))=m(B)$ for all $k$.

Comment: Wow, very nice!